# how to delete all facebook app request in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple problem. I want to delete all app request sent via my Facebook application. Facebook documentation gives following code to do that:

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[<request_id>_<user_id>]?access_token=[USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN]
```

My problem is how to make HTTP `DELETE` request in my rails application? 
I am using following code to make HTTP `GET` request:

```
client = HTTPClient.new
@data = client.get_content(URI.parse(
  URI.encode("https://graph.facebook.com/RequestID?access_token=AccessToken")
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`HTTPClient#delete`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.2.4/frames) method. I believe that's all you need. That should be smth like

```
client = HTTPClient.new
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{request_id}?access_token=#{access_token}"
data = client.delete url
```

Btw, why do you need that `URI.parse` and `URI.encode` stuff in you example?

And as you're dealing with Facebook I'd suggest looking at [rest-graph](https://github.com/godfat/rest-graph) gem. It's a pretty good tool for dealing with Facebook Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

If the above doesn't work you can also GET the url, but specify the method as delete:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/[<req id>]?access_token=[<access_token>]&method=delete"
```

This works for GET, POST, and DELETE.